# how Object.getPrototypeOf() work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn javascript and I was learning Object from Mozilla document. Everything was fine until I come to this example.

> It is the first example with the heading **Enumerate the properties of an
>   object**  on this link
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

***Here is code which i am  confused about. and later on i will explain what i am confuse about in this code***

```
var myCar = {
    make:'Ford',
    model:'Mushtag',
    year:1969,

}

function listAllProperties(o) {
    var objectToInspect;     
    var result = [];

    for(objectToInspect = o; objectToInspect !== null; objectToInspect = Object.getPrototypeOf(objectToInspect)) {  
      result = result.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objectToInspect));  
    }

    return result; 
}
```

**What I am confused about is the `for loop part`.**

I understand this section `objectToInspect = o;` *objectInspect* value will be equal to the argument when I call my function.

But next, two parts are confusing me,

```
objectToInspect !==null; objectToInspect= Object.getPrototypeOf(objectToInspect)
```

**What I understand by these two last parts**, that for the second time *objectToInspect* will be equal to *Object.getPrototypeOf(objectToInspect);* (If i am wrong let me know);

but I don't understand how this condition is going to met `objectToInspect !==null;`

If I am not clear I want to again say I am confused about how the **for loop is going to meet this condition objectToInspect !==null;** and going to exist the loop.

I did a huge google search and I read this link as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf

maybe I miss something, I am a beginner, 
***Again I am confused about the for loop statements, especially the second one***

I am calling my function with myCar object which is at the top of the code, and I also included that object in this question.

Comment: I think that if you're a beginner you should focus on learning the basics of javascript. The code you're showing us is a way to list properties of an object, as MDN says. Nowadays we have more elegant alternatives to achieve the same behavior such as for...in, Object.keys(o), etc. I recommend you to read the You Don't Know Js series of books, they are free.

Comment: Thanks @LucasDavidFerrero the aim is not learn how get property of object, the aims, do i understand how the for loop work.

Comment: Cause the `[[prototype]]` of `Object.prototype` is `null`, so the loop will exut at that root node.

Comment: @JonasW. and Lucas thanks i got my answer, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second condition `objectToInspect !== null` means the loop will terminate when the condition is met.

By putting `objectToInspect = Object.getPrototypeOf(objectToInspect)` on the third condition, you are traversing up the `Prototype` chain of the objectToInspect.

The prototype chain always ends at `null`.

> When it comes to inheritance, JavaScript only has one construct: objects. Each object has a private property which holds a link to another object called its prototype. That prototype object has a prototype of its own, and so on until an object is reached with null as its prototype. By definition, null has no prototype, and acts as the final link in this prototype chain.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

For example, suppose your `objectToInspect` was an array `[1, 2]`.

The prototype chain will be `Array.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null`

You can check this by passing `Object.prototype` to `Object.getPrototypeOf(..)`.

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype));
// prints 'null'
```

To see how we get to `null` from an array `[1, 2]`,

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf([1, 2]))));
// prints 'null'
```

Comment: Your answer is making sense to me and other as well, but your one is particularly clicking, lead me 4-5 times, i might understand, sorry beginners, Thanks for effort

Comment: *sorry let me 4-5 times

Comment: Thanks got it, the things you wrote in your qoute in the edit, thanks and very thanks it was difficult to explain it me but you did it. Thanks

Comment: No problem! And I strongly recommend the book `You don't know JS` just as Lucas did.

Comment: yep i will, i dont know how i stumble on to this topic but i did you dont know i was confused about this for more 6-7 hours, thanks again and i will read the book

Answer (score 2):

When debugging a for loop, it's sometimes helpful to turn it into a while loop.

```
function listAllProperties(o) {
    var objectToInspect = o;     
    var result = [];

    while(objectToInspect !== null) {  
      result = result.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objectToInspect)); 
      objectToInspect = Object.getPrototypeOf(objectToInspect);
    }

    return result; 
}
```

Let's run this function with a Number as input:

```
listAllProperties(Number(5))
// ["constructor", "toExponential", "toFixed", "toPrecision", "toString", "valueOf", "toLocaleString", "constructor", "__defineGetter__", "__defineSetter__", "hasOwnProperty", "__lookupGetter__", "__lookupSetter__", "isPrototypeOf", "propertyIsEnumerable", "toString", "valueOf", "__proto__", "toLocaleString"]
```

It listed the properties of Number, then Object, then when getting the prototype of Object, it got null, so stopped the loop.

Comment: Thanks i am reading your answer again so i can understand, give me some time and thank for the answer

Comment: Thanks i don't know which answer is better but other one i was able to understand Thanks for the help +1